# How to add an element to a JSON array file from a form using JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, backend

I have this html form to add data to a json array file

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AddBook.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="add">
            <input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="issued" name="issued">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <script>
                var x = document.getElementById("add");
                var isbn = x.elements[0].value;
                var title = x.elements[1].value;
                var author = x.elements[2].value;
                var issued = x.elements[3].value;
                write(isbn,title,author,issued);
        </script>
```

and below is the AddBook.js

```
function write(isbn, title, author, issued) {
  const fs = require(['fs'], function (fs){  
  const data = fs.readFileSync('js/book.json');
  let jsonStr = data.toString();
  const obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

  obj.books.push({
    isbn,
    title,
    author,
    issued,
  });
  jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(jsonStr);
  fs.truncate('js/book.json', 0, () => {
    fs.writeFile('js/book.json', jsonStr, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
      }
    });
  });
  });
}
```

The problem is that the below script works as a standalone file but stops working as soon as it is used with the HTML. 
How can I make this script work with the form

Comment: JavaScript inside a browser is usually restricted from accessing the file system. As far as I know - there is no way around that, except using a backend in nodejs or some such.

Comment: @fredrik do you think i can do this using php?
I must however inform you that the json file is on the server

Comment: If it's on the server it really is impossible to do in the HTML on the client. If you have PHP and know how to use it, then yes it's possible to do that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a function to run on the submission on your form. Something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AddBook.js"></script>
    <script>
        function writeToJSON(){
            var x = document.getElementById("add");
            var isbn = x.elements[0].value;
            var title = x.elements[1].value;
            var author = x.elements[2].value;
            var issued = x.elements[3].value;
            write(isbn,title,author,issued);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="add" onsubmit="writeToJSON()">
        <input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="issued" name="issued">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```